# Cant get days and time in multiple array

Tags: php, date, datetime

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $day = $_POST['day'];
    $from = $_POST['from'];
    $to = $_POST['to'];
    for($i=0;$i<count($day);$i++) {
        $days = $day[$i];
        $froms = $from[$i];
        $tos = $to[$i];
        echo 'From'.$froms.'<br> To'.$tos;
    }
}
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="Monday"> Monday | From <input type="time" name="from[]" to="from[]"> To<input type="time" name="to[]" to="to[]"><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="Tuesday"> Tuesday| From <input type="time" name="from[]" to="from[]"> To<input type="time" name="to[]" to="to[]"><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="Wednesday"> Wednesday | From <input type="time" name="from[]" to="from[]"> To<input type="time" name="to[]" to="to[]"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I am not getting from time and to time when I submit, I can get either from time or to time only

Comment: remove `[]` from name attribute

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's this supposed to do: `to="to[]"`?

Comment: I want to store multiple records in DB actually

Comment: Did the answer work for you

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me.  But there may be confusion in your mind.  Day is a checkbox, so if its not ticked, you dont get a day but you still get a time. If only one day is ticked, the array size is 1.

See modified code

```php
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $day = $_POST['day'] ?? '';  //<---- if no day is selected this will be null
    $from = $_POST['from'];
    $to = $_POST['to'];
    for($i=0;$i<2;$i++) {        //<---- Using 2 here as the length of array days varies
        $days = $day[$i] ?? '';  //<---- Similarly here
        $froms = $from[$i];
        $tos = $to[$i];
        echo 'Day'.$days.' From'.$froms.' To'.$tos.'<br>';
    }
}
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="Monday"> Monday | From <input type="time" name="from[]" to="from[]"> To<input type="time" name="to[]" to="to[]"><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="Tuesday"> Tuesday| From <input type="time" name="from[]" to="from[]"> To<input type="time" name="to[]" to="to[]"><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="Wednesday"> Wednesday | From <input type="time" name="from[]" to="from[]"> To<input type="time" name="to[]" to="to[]"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```